# Can I insert the feature image inside the content, after any paragraph?

Tags: post-thumbnails, the-content

I want to display the feature image inside a post text, perhaps after the third or fourth paragraph (or any) into the_content.

Searching the site I've found this code, by Amit:

```
add_filter('the_content', function($content)
{
   $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
   $img = '<img src="'.$url.'" alt="" title=""/>';
   $content = preg_replace('#(<p>.*?</p>)#','$1'.$img, $content, 1);
   return $content;
});
```

Works like a charm, but I can't figure out how include the post_thumbnail after a defined paragraph (not only the second). Can anybody point me on the right direction?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: How would this "defined" paragraph would look like?

Comment: Just as any paragraph... I don't know the content. I can 'inject' a class on the <p> tag with jQuery
    `$('p:nth-child(5n+1) span.Noted').addClass('Note1');`. Perhaps it helps.

Answer (score 0):

we can solve this problem by creating a shortcode so that you can insert the featured image where ever you want through the editor itself.Shortcode is a keyword that we created.Any number of custom shortcodes can be created and used either in template or in editor as like wordpress default shortcodes like [gallery].

write a function in **functions.php** to retrieve featured image .

```
function myTheme_featured_image($atts, $content){
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(),$atts, 'featured');
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
     return "<div class='featured_wrapper_div'>".
        get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'thumbnail' ) 
           ."</div>";
}
add_shortcode('featured', 'myTheme_featured_image');
```

'featured' is our custom shortcode name.In your post/ page editor, give the shortcode name like the following where you want the image, after or before any paragraph / any line / anywhere..

```
[featured][/featured]
```

you can style the wrapper div  **'featured_wrapper_div'**  through style.css so that the image fit as you like.
Since we are adding this in our editor, it will display when you call ***the_content()*** in template

Since we are adding this in editor, it will show if you call ***the_content()*** in tempalte.

It will work..